# How to include HTML files in karma frontend testing via jasmine

Tags: javascript, html, automated-tests, karma-jasmine, karma-runner

I'm trying to create frontend headless browser testing via karma/jasmine, but it seems as if the HTML files were not loaded, only the JS files. Whenever I include a JS file (among the `files: [ ]`), it is correctly executed, e.g. console.log is written out to the terminal. However, when I include any HTML files, it doesn't do anything; a script called in it is not executed, and I cannot access its elements either.

karma.conf.js:

```
module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({
    basePath: '',
    frameworks: ['jasmine'],
    files: [
      '../js/jquery-2.1.3.min.js',
      'index.html',
      'test.js'
    ],
    exclude: [
    ],
    preprocessors: {
    },
    reporters: ['progress'],
    port: 9876,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
    autoWatch: false,
    browsers: ['PhantomJS'],
    singleRun: true,
    concurrency: Infinity
  })
}
```

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
      <script>console.log("Script in HTML")</script>
  </head>
  <body>
          <p id = "my_id1">
              Text in my_id1.
          </p>
  </body>
</html>
```

test.js:

```
describe("A suite", function() {
  console.log( $("#my_id1").text() ); // currently outputs empty string
  it("contains spec with an expectation", function() {
    expect(true).toBe(true);
  });
});
```

So the question is: how could I include HTML files so that they are correctly loaded in the browser (so that I can manipulate them via the JS code)?

Answer (score 1):

I now have a working solution.

To karma.conf.js I add automatic conversion of HTML to JS:

```
preprocessors: {
  '**/*.html': ['html2js']
},
```

and

```
html2JsPreprocessor: {
  // strip this from the file path
  stripPrefix: 'public/',

  // prepend this to the file path
  prependPrefix: 'served/',

  // or define a custom transform function
  processPath: function(filePath) {
    // Drop the file extension
    return filePath.replace(/\.html$/, '');
  }
}
```

And in test.js I append the converted HTML-JS file to the body of the page:

```
$("body").append(window.__html__.index);
```

This correctly loads the index.html.

However, for some reason this does not work when I
give a relative path for the file, e.g.:

```
files: [
  '../js/jquery-2.1.3.min.js',
  '../index.html', // instead of just 'index.html'
  'test.js'
],
```

And I still don't know why simply loading HTML does not work.